# how to center tablenotes in a threeparttable

Tags: tables, threeparttable, tablenotes

Given the threeparttable

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{caption}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            abc &   def &   ghi     \\ \midrule
            abc1    &   def1    &   ghi1    \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item Source: xyz
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

how can I center the tablenotes (or a single item, if this should be easier), so that the tablenote is horizontally aligned with the caption of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `\tnote` directives and have a single line in the `tablenotes` environment, you are basically misusing (abusing, really) a key part of the `threeparttable` machinery. Don't do it. In such cases, just issue a `\centering` directive immediately before the line that follows the `tabular` environment in order to achieve your formatting objective.

If you do have one or more `\tnote` directives, I suggest you load the `threeparttable` package with the option `flushleft`.

Both possibilities are explored in the following screenshot and associated LaTeX code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb] 
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable} % Case 1: no '\tnote' directives
        \caption{Caption}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
            \toprule
            abc     &   def     &   ghi     \\ \midrule
            abcde1  &   defgh1  &   ghijk1  \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

        \smallskip\footnotesize\centering % <-- note the '\centering' directive
        Source: xyz
    \end{threeparttable}    

    \bigskip\bigskip

    \begin{threeparttable} % Case 2: with '\tnote' directives
        \caption{Caption}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
            \toprule
            abc     &   def     &   ghi\tnote{a} \\ \midrule
            abcde1  &   defgh1  &   ghijk1       \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

        \smallskip
        \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[a] Source: xyz
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this did work. As you mentioned I tried to (ab)use the threeparttable only for the source below the table itself. I found a workaround where I put "Source: xyz" in a starred caption below the table and therefore can omit threeparttable entirely.

Comment: @Lukas - You're welcome. Don't give up too quickly on the `threeparttable` machinery, though. It's very handy (essential, really) if you need to limit the width of the caption and other explanatory material (such as "Source: xyz") to the width of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @Miko thanks for the information, I will keep it in my mind for future tasks. Regarding my workaround with the starred caption: Is there a possibility to change the space before and after the caption* without affecting the unstarred command? Or should I open a new question for this?

Comment: @Lukas - Please post a new query.